# Web skype empty in Chrome?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, skype

Has anyone experienced that you go into web skype on Chrome and see all previous communications gone? Just like you're loging into a new account.

This has been happening to me for months. I first switched to Firefox, but now to make it work I have to open incognito mode on chrome. It works for a week or two, then I kill it and start a new incognito.

Has anyone any idea how to solve this? After months of not using web skype on the non-incognito chrome, I still log into an empty screen.

I tried deleting cookies, deleting /temp. Nothing helped.

Comment: I think I've been experiencing this on Windows 8.1 at work, so I think it's a Skype bug.

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks. So it may be indeed like we joked that some junior is pushing web skype updates without proper testing :).